# Не правильный расчет фактора масштабирования

Tags: c++, изображения, sfml, масштабирование

Уже не знаю каким боком мне что-то переписать в методе вычисления масштабирования, дабы он дал правильный результат на выходе.

Т.к. как только `Y` становится меньше чем `X`, масштабирование по `Y` либо совсем не пересчитывается, либо дает не верный результат на выходе, в результате чего происходит вот такая картина:

Первый расчет:
[image: Нормальный расчет]
Перерасчет во время рендера, при изменении размеров окна
[image: ERROR]

Методы расчета:

```
static double positive_infinity = (double)1.0 / (double)(0.0);
static double negative_infinity = (double)-1.0 / (double)(0.0);

static bool is_zero(double value)
{
    return abs(value) < 10.0 * DBL_EPSILON;
}

static sf::Vector2f compute_scale_factor(sf::Vector2f original_size, sf::Vector2f real_size)
{
    float scale_x = 1.0f, scale_y = 1.0f;

    bool is_constrained_width = original_size.x == positive_infinity;
    bool is_constrained_height = original_size.y == positive_infinity;

    scale_x = (is_zero(real_size.x)) ? 0.0 : original_size.x / real_size.x;
    scale_y = (is_zero(real_size.y)) ? 0.0 : original_size.y / real_size.y;

    if (!is_constrained_width)
    {
        scale_x = scale_y;
    }
    else if (!is_constrained_height)
    {
        scale_y = scale_x;
    }
    else
    {
        double minscale = scale_x < scale_y ? scale_x : scale_y;
        double maxscale = scale_x > scale_y ? scale_x : scale_y;
        scale_x = scale_y = minscale > maxscale ? minscale : maxscale;
    }

    return sf::Vector2f(scale_x, scale_y);
}
```

Comment: Что в этом коде `original_size`, а что `real_size`? Что-то из этого наверное размер окна, а что-то - размер видео? Кроме того, деления на ноль и сравнения `original_size.x == positive_infinity` выглядят крайне подозрительно.

Comment: `original_size` исходный размер, `real_size` ширина, высота к которой необходимо масштабировать, с сохранением пропорций.

Comment: @VTT: `Кроме того, деления на ноль` но разве не так расчитывается значение `Infinity`?

Comment: Дело в том, что деление на ноль и появление бесконечностей обычно указывают на ошибки в коде. Конкретно кусок `static double positive_infinity = (double)1.0 / (double)(0.0);` у меня даже не скомпилировался ибо vc++ протестует против такого безобразия даже вне `constexpr`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как я понимаю, тут нужно масштабирование с сохранением пропорций, чтобы видео аккуратно влезало в окно, но потенциально с добавлением черных полос, если пропорции окна не соответствуют пропорциям видео, ака letterbox:

```
static sf::Vector2f compute_scale_factor(sf::Vector2f input_size, sf::Vector2f window_size)
{
    auto const width_based_scale{window_size.x / input_size.x};
    auto const width_based_height{input_size.y * width_based_scale};
    if(width_based_height <= window_size.y)
    {
        return sf::Vector2f{width_based_scale, width_based_scale};
    }
    auto const height_based_scale{window_size.y / input_size.y};
    auto const height_based_width{input_size.x * height_based_scale};
    assert(height_based_width <= window_size.x);
    return sf::Vector2f{height_based_scale, height_based_scale};
}
```

Comment: Хм, я начинаю подозревать что проблема в самом `SFML`: http://joxi.ru/Dr89woni4KKXjm, изображение не растянулось по высоте, когда ширина больше высоты. Еще и потеряло пропорции.

Comment: @LLENN А что потом с возвращаемым значением происходит? Может оно как-то не правильно используется?

Comment: Оно передается в `sf::Sprite` дабы он сделал `Scale`.

Comment: @LLENN Не могу сказать ничего определенного, не видя код... Может у вас еще до этого что-то не так идет, например размер вьюпорта не обновляется.

Comment: Точно, закоментировал ресайз вью, и забыл убрать... Да, скаллирование правильное! http://joxi.ru/nAy65eXiY9987r

Answer (score 0):

`original_size.x` сделайте `float(original_size.x)` перед делением. Тогда в `if(!is_constrained_width)` уберите отрицание.

Comment: Структура `sf::Vector2f` содержит поля с типом `float`

Comment: Тогда в `if(!is_constrained_width)` уберите отрицание.

Comment: Предложенное вами решение, никаким образом не решит проблему. т.к. в таком случае масштабирование будет считаться в корне не верным.

Comment: проверьте оба ифа на практике